# Can you teach Alexa a new skill by voice?

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

Can you enable a new skill in Amazon Echo by voice?

Ideally, I'd like to ask Alexa which skills they offer related to a specific category (like dictionary), then I'd like to enable one.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to enable any skill by voice, provided you already know the name of the skill.

The [Amazon documentation](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201848700) for adding skills is relatively straightforward:

> If you know the exact name of the skill you want, **you can say, "Enable [skill name] skill".** Some skills may require you to link to an existing account and a separate subscription in order to use the skill.

However, this requires you to know the name of the skill beforehand, which may not be particularly useful. To get around this, you can take advantage of the Amazon-developed [Skill Finder](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Amazon-Skill-Finder/dp/B01GGW79U4) skill. This allows you to search through skills by voice with the following commands:

> Alexa, tell Skill Finder to give me the Skill of the Day
>
> Alexa, tell Skill Finder to give me the newest skills
>
> Alexa, tell Skill Finder to give me top skills
>
> Alexa, tell Skill Finder to list categories
>
> Alexa, tell Skill Finder to list the newest skills in the education category
>
> Alexa, tell Skill Finder to list the top skills in the games category

You can enable this skill with *"Alexa, enable Skill Finder skill"*, and then the above commands will be supported.